# Read file byte by byte in D

Tags: windows, file, d, dmd

How do I read a file byte by byte in D?

What I have is an open file, say:

```
auto f = File("test.bin");
```

Now I need to read bytes, say:

```
ubyte first = fgetc(f); // this is whishfull thinking
ubyte second = fgetc(f);
```

I'd also need to be able to do other stuff, like reading uints, ushorts, skipping (fseek) etc. for instance (C again):

```
fread(&third,2,1,fptr);
```

---

bonus question is if it is possible to read a struct in one go, say I have

```
struct Test { ubyte a,b,c; uint d,e;  /* etc */ }
```

can I read it from a binary file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phobos provides you with an excellent [byChunk](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#.File.byChunk) function for this purpose.

You really do not want to read file by byte, but rather by chunk, and preferrably a chunk the same size as the page (typically 4 KiB).

Comment: this is nice, but also `rawRead` is nice. Btw, any ideas on reading/writing a struct?

Comment: PS. nobody stops you from calling `fgetc()` if you want. D can call any C function anyway.

Comment: Sure, but i'd rather stick to D if possible. So.... any ideas on struct reading/writing?

Comment: It all goes through the C RT anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own `fgetc` function that does `rawRead` on the `File` object into a buffer and then returns the next available element in the buffer.

An alternative is to use the `core.stdc.stdio` module and do C-style file I/O:

```
import cio = core.stdc.stdio;

...

FILE* fp = cio.fopen("test.bin", "rb");
foreach (int i; 0..100) {
    auto c = cio.fgetc(fp);
    ...
}
cio.fclose(fp);
```

---

As for reading structs, that can also be done with `rawRead`. For example:

```
struct Test {
    align(1):
    ubyte a, b;
    short c;
}

...

Test t;
auto binFile = File("test.bin", "r");
binFile.rawRead((&t)[0..1]);  // Read into the buffer made up of t
writefln("%x %x %x", t.a, t.b, t.c);
```

Comment: great, I like the struct read; but is `align` safe? I dont want to sacrifice the overall corectnes / performacne for the sake of reading

Comment: I just used `align(1)` as an example. The member alignment will have to match the data you're reading when you're populating a struct with a binary blob coming from a file.